# Run a launcher on the desktop

Tags: system

Let me explain.

With Ubuntu when I extracted a game in the download folder I go to the game file and click on the launcher that launches on the desktop.

[image]

With Elementary os it's impossible we have to launch it through the terminal.

What tool does Elementary lack for being able to do like Ubuntu. After all his base is Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .desktop to launch the launcher, its something like a shorcut in Windows.

To create it just write the following in a .desktop file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name= (The name you wnt to appear) 
Comment= (If you want something to appear when you put the mouse over it)
Exec= (route to launcher binary file)
Icon= (route to the icon you want for it)
Type=Application
```

Also, you may want to install https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.spheras.desktopfolder to be able to place things in desktop.

Comment: Easier: get AppEditor from the App center and create your own icon (instead of fiddling with text files) !